# Is IPTV good and free of buffering? Should I use a set top box for it?

Tags: streaming, tv, iptv

If you have had experience with IPTV for streaming live channels. Tell me how good it is, compared to satellite and cable TV, because I tried streaming live sport on the internet on my laptop from free streaming sites, and almost always I get buffering problems, even with my lightning fast internet connection (500 MBPS). Nearly every time, whether in HD or SD, the stream freezes, forcing me to refresh the page and making me miss key moments, which occurred. The frequency of this freeze buffering varies depending on the streaming source. I haven't tried paid streaming sources yet.
I am using a router, and the problem occurs regardless of whether I'm connected on WiFi or by Ethernet cable.
So how good is IPTV for where you can't afford a single moment of freezing and buffering? And is it better with a set top box than with a laptop? And which would be the best IPTV providers out there, preferably ones which provide service worldwide ?

Answer (score 3):

IPTV works fine without any buffering issues as long as you use a reputable provider. And no, I am not talking about the illicit providers that provide streams to Kodi add-ons, but rather IPTV coming from your ISP or Telco - like O2 in Europe or ATT in the US.

The technology is mature and provides good experience, regardless if you are using set top box or a laptop - but you need a provider that knows what they are doing and have access to legitimate content.

I have watched Olympic games live without a single buffering issue from CZTV1 across the world - just needed the right subscription...